# How to know if user can read the content of a directory in swift

Tags: swift

In order to avoid a known bug, I need to kwnow before enumerating a directory, if the user can read it.

How can I do that in swift (most recent version, using Xcode and MAC OS most recent version)?

**More info:**
Trying to enumerate a directory in swift can lead to an application crash if the user can't access it. There is no way to catch an error to prevent the crash but it only happen if the user can't access the directory. So, knowing beforehand if the directory can be read (thus enumerated) would help in preventing the crash.

**Cashable code:**

There is this example : https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2872 reported by **Timothy Wood**

And this example : http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2016/Oct/msg00166.html reported by **Jean Suisse**

Comment: Could you show the crashable code?

Comment: @matt Well matt... it is a known bug. There is nothing in the cashable code that will answer the question. No need to downvote. This doesn't help. The answer to this question (i.e. how to avoid enumerating inaccessible folders), however, could help others.

Comment: It would still be very helpful to see the code that leads to the crash, and perhaps some references to the bug you are talking about. (You don't know whether it was matt who cast the downvote, btw)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I will try to find some reference. I only have my rdar flagged as duplicate. About the code part: trust me there is nothing to see... It just gives EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when trying to enumerate certain non-readable directories

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have provided two examples taken from the net to prove that it is a known bug. Is it useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for this bug is provided in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) for Xcode 8.1. To quote the release notes:

> Some Objective-C methods in the SDKs may incorrectly annotate or
>   assume a type to be `nonnull` rather than `nullable`. A type that Swift
>   treats as a struct, such as `NSURL` (`Foundation.URL`) or `NSDate`
>   (`Foundation.Date`), results in a run-time crash in a method with a name
>   like `bridgeFromObjectiveC`; in other cases, it can lead to crashes or
>   undefined behavior in user code. If you identify such a method, please
>   file a report at bugreport.apple.com. As a workaround, add a
>   trampoline function in Objective-C with the correct nullability
>   annotations. For example, the following function will allow you to
>   call
>   `FileManager`'s `enumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:)`
>   method with an error handler that accepts `nil` URLs:

```
static inline NSDirectoryEnumerator<NSURL *> * _Nullable
fileManagerEnumeratorAtURL(NSFileManager *fileManager, NSURL * _Nonnull url, NSArray<NSURLResourceKey> * _Nullable keys, NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions options, BOOL (^ _Nullable errorHandler)(NSURL * _Nullable errorURL, NSError * _Nonnull error)) {
     return [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:url includingPropertiesForKeys:keys options:options errorHandler:^(NSURL * _Nonnull errorURL, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
      return errorHandler(errorURL, error);
   }];
}
```

> This function can be included in your bridging header (for an app or
>   test target) or umbrella header (for a framework target). (27749845)

The steps to take:

1) Add a new .m file to your project called DirectoryEnumeratorGlue.m. When you add it Xcode will ask you whether you want it to create a bridging header for you, say yes. Put the following in DirectoryEnumeratorGlue.m:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator<NSURL *> * _Nullable
fileManagerEnumeratorAtURL(NSFileManager * _Nonnull fileManager, NSURL * _Nonnull url, NSArray<NSURLResourceKey> * _Nullable keys, NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions options, BOOL (^ _Nullable errorHandler)(NSURL * _Nullable errorURL, NSError * _Nonnull error)) {
     return [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:url includingPropertiesForKeys:keys options:options errorHandler:^(NSURL * _Nonnull errorURL, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
      return errorHandler(errorURL, error);
   }];
}
```

2) Add a new .h file to your project, named DirectoryEnumeratorGlue.h. Put the following in DirectoryEnumeratorGlue.h:

```
extern NSDirectoryEnumerator<NSURL *> * _Nullable
fileManagerEnumeratorAtURL(NSFileManager * _Nonnull fileManager, NSURL * _Nonnull url, NSArray<NSURLResourceKey> * _Nullable keys, NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions options, BOOL (^ _Nullable errorHandler)(NSURL * _Nullable errorURL, NSError * _Nonnull error));
```

3) Add the following to your bridging header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DirectoryEnumeratorGlue.h"
```

4) Replace the call to FileManager.default.enumerator in your Swift call with something like this:

```
    let enumerator = fileManagerEnumeratorAtURL(FileManager.default, url, [],  [], {
        (errorURL, error) in
        return true
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your really helpful answer. I am glad there are still "low-rep people" willing to help. I fear "elders" have lost their way in an everlasting "where is the code?" / "what have you tried?" / "what are you trying to do?" quest, to the point they are blindly asking the question even when not relevant. Back on topic: So, I should just add this line in my code? But where? My app is swift only and does not have a bridging header.

Comment: I added directions for adding the glue code to your project, hope that helps.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much for your help.